# How do you prevent file confusion if version-control keywords are forbidden?

Tags: version-control, version-control-keywords

At least two brilliant programmers, Linus Torvalds and Guido von Rossum, disparage the practice of putting keywords into a file that expand to show the version number, last author, etc.

I know how keyword differences clutter up diffs. One of the reasons I like SlickEdit's DiffZilla is because it can be set to skip leading comments.

However, I have vivid memories of team-programming where we had four versions of a file   (two different releases, a customer one-off, and the development version) all open for patching at the same time, and was quite helpful to verify with a glance that each time we navigated to an included header we got the proper one, and each time we pasted code the source and destination were what we expected.

There is also the where-did-this-file-come-from problem that arises when a hasty developer copies a file from one place to another using the file system, rather than checking it out of the repository using the tool; or, more defensibly, when files under control in locations A, B, and C need to be marshalled (with cherry-picking) into a distribution location D.

In places where VCS keywords are banned, how do you cope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I imagine Linus and Guido have reasons for disliking keywords that don't apply to small-team corporate development.

An `$Id$` tag for instance, has what you could consider to be a global version number.  Linux and I guess also Python development is fragmented enough that no number can be global.  Lots of people have their own repositories all over the place that would fill in their own `$Id$` values and then those patches might be sent to Linus or Guido's repositories where they don't make any sense.

However, in your environment, you probably have one central repository which would assign these and it would be fine.  Sounds like you're using git.  I wonder if it's possible to configure the central git repository to do tag substitution while the local developer repositories don't.  Or perhaps it's better to get the commit hash in the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used VCS keywords in my entire career, over 30 years. From the most primitive VCS system I've used, up to the present (TFS), I've used some other structure to understand "where I am".

I am rarely in a situation where I've only got one file to work with. I've usually got all the other files necessary to build the project or set of projects. I usually use branching (or *streams* on one occasion), and I'm working on some slice of the given branch or stream.

If I'm working on multiple branches or streams, I'll have one directory tree for each. All I need to do to know what file I'm working on is check the file path, at the very worst.

At the very best, the version control system will tell you exactly which version of the file you're working on, what the change history is, who else is working on different versions of the file, and anything else you'd care to know.